# Function called, console says it is anonymous

Tags: javascript, variables, console, undefined

I'm having an issue making this two dice game. I think the problem is the diceDOM variables, I get an error message in the console saying "Cannot set property 'display' of undefined at init" and in the console it says that the init(); calling is undefined.

The two dice I want to save within that variable have the same class .dice. Is it because I should save them separately in an array?

The code is below, I omitted the code in between:

```
 var scores, roundScore, activePlayer, dice1, dice2, diceDOM, gamePlaying;

// var userInput = Number(document.getElementById("userScore").value);
diceDOM = document.querySelectorAll(".dice");
init();

function init() {
    roundScore = 0;
    scores = [0, 0];
    activePlayer = 0;
    diceDOM.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("score-0").textContent = 0;
    document.getElementById("score-1").textContent = 0;
    document.getElementById("current-0").textContent = 0;
    document.getElementById("current-1").textContent = 0;
    document.querySelector(".player-0-panel").classList.remove("active");
    document.querySelector(".player-0-panel").classList.add("active");
    document.querySelector(".player-1-panel").classList.remove("active");
    document.querySelector(".player-0-panel").classList.remove("winner");
    document.querySelector(".player-1-panel").classList.remove("winner");
    document.getElementById("name-0").textContent = "Player 1";
    document.getElementById("name-1").textContent = "Player 2";
    document.getElementById("userScore").value = "";
    gamePlaying = true;
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: ```diceDOM = document.querySelectorAll(".dice");``` returns an array of elements. So you cannot do something like ```diceDOM.style.display```. You have to loop through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

diceDOM is a node list, which means it's a collection of elements and it doesn't have a style property, you have to iterate over each diceDOM element and set its display to none, so instead of:

```
diceDOM.style.display = "none";
```

Do:

```
diceDOM.forEach(function(dice) {
    dice.style.display = "none";
})
```

Comment: Solved. I thought it was something related to that but did not know how to approach it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `querySelectorAll`, it returns all elements that match in a NodeList object. if you just want the first div with class `dice`, you could do

```
diceDOM = document.querySelector(".dice");
```

Otherwise you would have to access each element ->

```
diceDOM[index].style.display = "none";
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The `document.querySelectorAll` returns with an `Array`!

You should use

```
diceDOM[0].style.display = "none";
```

Of course if you have more `.dice` elements, then you have to iterate trough the diceDOM and set the style item by item:

```
diceDOM.forEach((i) => { i.style.display = 'none'; });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)